# What sytles and templates are available to write a brief?

Tags: style, resources

I want to write a brief on a conference I recently attended. What resources and styles should I consider to make this document effective and professional?

Comment: Besides that I do not know what a brief is, you ask a very broad question. Could you be more specific? What is "effective" what "professional" what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, I could write a brief that had the style of a bibliography. It might convey the necessary information but the manner might be confusing to the reader. Since I've never written a brief, I asked this question for guidance. Are there standard templates for writing briefs? Are there any standard styles for writing briefs? Perhaps there are styles for briefs, just as there are styles for writing dissertations, plays, anthologies, bibliographies, resumes, menus, etc.

Comment: @John Smithers: perhaps the answers will clarify what a brief is.

Comment: @zundarz: Mostly it would depend on the target audience of your report (= brief); if they are your bosses than you should focus on what benefits/caveats you gleaned; if your peers, then short summaries of the various speakers' talks would suffice. Look for templates on 'Reports'.

Comment: @slashmais: Where are you coming from? Well, let me explain you the system. Do you see the number next to my comment? That means this number of people disagree with you. Now let me explain you "common sense": I do not need to know "briefs" to tell you that the question is too broad to answer according to the standards of this community. As I have exposed in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Google for "[template for conference report](http://www.google.com/search?q=template%20for%20conference%20report)" - it will give you numerous examples/templates.